# Angular 4 Material Datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

How to make angular 5 official date picker pick only month and year and only year?

here is the code...

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name suggests, the DatePicker is built to pick dates.

There isn't a way you can only use it to pick only month and/or year.